# What does 对性 in 因为对性疫苗的保护会随着时间的推移而降低 mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> 古纳迪希望未来新冠肺炎的剧增，不会对我国人民产生重大影响。希望继续保持很高的免疫水平，因为在未来六个月内，我国公民的免疫水平将很低，**因为对性疫苗的保护会随着时间的推移而降低**。
> <sub>[卫长：千万不可掉以轻心](https://guojiribao.com/?p=201008)，印尼要闻，2022年08月26日</sub>

I'm not clear on what 对性 means in the last part here.  I'm guessing 对 means "corresponding" (like in 对象) and 性 means something like "type" or "kind", but I don't feel I fully understand what it's saying.  ([Google Translates](https://translate.google.cn/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%E5%B8%8C%E6%9C%9B%E7%BB%A7%E7%BB%AD%E4%BF%9D%E6%8C%81%E5%BE%88%E9%AB%98%E7%9A%84%E5%85%8D%E7%96%AB%E6%B0%B4%E5%B9%B3%EF%BC%8C%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA%E5%9C%A8%E6%9C%AA%E6%9D%A5%E5%85%AD%E4%B8%AA%E6%9C%88%E5%86%85%EF%BC%8C%E6%88%91%E5%9B%BD%E5%85%AC%E6%B0%91%E7%9A%84%E5%85%8D%E7%96%AB%E6%B0%B4%E5%B9%B3%E5%B0%86%E5%BE%88%E4%BD%8E%EF%BC%8C%E5%9B%A0%E4%B8%BA%E5%AF%B9%E6%80%A7%E7%96%AB%E8%8B%97%E7%9A%84%E4%BF%9D%E6%8A%A4%E4%BC%9A%E9%9A%8F%E7%9D%80%E6%97%B6%E9%97%B4%E7%9A%84%E6%8E%A8%E7%A7%BB%E8%80%8C%E9%99%8D%E4%BD%8E%E3%80%82&op=translate) gives "sexual vaccines" but this is surely just plain wrong; 性 does not pertain to sex here.)

**Question**: What does 对性 in 因为对性疫苗的保护会随着时间的推移而降低 mean?

Comment: 对性疫苗 could be typo of 針對性疫苗 ( targeted vaccines)

Comment: Bad sentence. Should be modified to "因为(对**抗**性)疫苗的保护**期**会随着时间(的推移)而降低".

Comment: @r13 The second suggestion is wrong. “…保护期…随着时间…降低” translates to "the duration (of protection) decreases by time", and makes much less sense than "the protection (itself) decreases by time".

Comment: Yes. If 期 changes to 效力 or 功效 will be better, as the effectiveness of most of the vaccines will decrease with the lapse of time. The sentence has room for modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google-ing for “对性疫苗”](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%E5%AF%B9%E6%80%A7%E7%96%AB%E8%8B%97%22) suggests it's a typo from **针**对性疫苗 (specialized vaccine).

Comment: You should at least reference the originator in your writing after copying his/her idea. Or, add the source that confirms 对性 was a typo of 针对性, or state that the latter is mainly a "best guess" (which is not a bad guess though).

Comment: @r13 It's impossible to confirm that this is indeed a typo. But anyone done the same Google search will probably draw the same conclusion that this is the most viable interpretation.